# how to show currently logged in user info using id and sessions

Tags: php, session

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $status="verified";
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","Hai");
    $db=mysql_select_db('Hai',$con);
    //include('includes/connection.php');



    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        //$name=$_POST['u_name'];
        $pass=$_POST['pass'];

        $select_user = "select * from users where user_email ='$email' AND user_pass ='$pass'";

        $query = mysql_query($select_user);

        $check_user = mysql_num_rows($query);



        //$_SESSION['uemail'] = "   ".$email;
        $_SESSION['uname'] = "    ".$email;
        //print_r($info);
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $id;


        if($check_user == 1)
        {
            echo"<script>window.open('profile_desigin.php','_self')</script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>alert('Invalid Password Or Email! Try Again')</script>";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($_POST['uname']))
        {
            header('location:main_desigin.php');
        }
    }


?>
```

Comment: Avoid using mysql_* functions. They are already removed from PHP 7.

Comment: what is your problem ? 
you should watch sql injection too

Answer (score 0):

Things you need to do :

1. STOP using `mysql_*` functions they are depreciated and no longer supported. Use either `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements.
2. Don't store passwords in plain text, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for better password security.
3. Always use prepared statements when you are querying database using user input.
4. Use prepared statements always.

now back to your question to show the current loggedin users's details :

**profile_desigin.php**

```
<?php
        session_start()
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id'])){

            // query what ever you want from the database where userid = $_SESSION['user_id']


        }else{

            echo "you need to login to view this page";
            //redirect to login page
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to put all that you need in the

sessions

```
$_session['user_id'] = $row['id'];
```

To see what is in the session you can echo the variable

```
Echo $session['user_id'];
```